# looping in lists of csv files names

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am having some issues with my below code. The purpose of the code is to take a list of lists that within each of the lists, carries a series of csv files. I want to loop through each of these lists (one at a time) and pull in only the csv files found in the respective list.

my current code is accumulating all the data instead of starting from scratch each time it loops thru. First loop, use all the csv files in 0th index, second loop, use all the csv files in the 1st index - but dont accumulate

```
path = "C:/DataFolder/"
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
fileChunks = [['2003.csv','2004.csv','2005.csv'],['2006.csv','2007.csv','2008.csv']]


for i in range(len(fileChunks)):
"""move empty dataframe here"""

df = pd.DataFrame()

    for file_ in fileChunks[i]:
        df_temp = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col = None, names = names, parse_dates=True)
        df = df.append(df_temp)
```

note: fileChunks is derived from a function, and it spits out a list of lists like the example above

any help to documentation or pointing out my error would be great - I want to learn from this. thank you.

EDIT
It seems that moving the empty dataframe to within the first for loop works.

Comment: What is the desired content of `df`? Right now you define it outside of the outermost loop, so it contains all of the data. Perhaps you need a list of dataframes instead?

Comment: I'm really not clear what you're asking.  In your example above, do you want two files, each containing data from the three files in each group?

Comment: @Alexander my goal was to purely load the data into the dataframe, rinse and repeat. see my edit.  I think I answered it

Comment: It's still not clear.  What do you mean don't accumulate? Do you simply want to unnest your list of lists and read every file?

Comment: @Alexander at the moment, when it loops thru the csv files (one list at a time) lets assume there are 50 lines per csv file, load 3 at a time. My dataframe after the entire loop is ran, goes from 150 to 300 lines in my dataframe, but I want it to load one set of list at a time, so the dataframe should loop and be 150 lines long, loop again and 150 lines long, instead it goes from 150 lines and then 300 lines (accumulation)

Answer (score 2):

This should unnest your files and read each separately using a list comprehension, and then join them all using `concat`.  This is much more efficient than appending each read to a growing dataframe.

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=None, names=names, parse_dates=True) 
                for chunk in fileChunks for file_ in chunk], 
               ignore_index=True)


>>> [file_ for chunk in fileChunks for file_ in chunk]
['2003.csv', '2004.csv', '2005.csv', '2006.csv', '2007.csv', '2008.csv']
```